# Multiple values for one field

Tags: gwt, gxt

In GXT I want to create a form where a single field can have multiple values. so once one value is provided user should have option enter another value for the same field, similar to how we attach files in an e-mail.. what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to provide a button with plus symbol in the form. Clicking that button should add a field to the form dynamically. User can use that field to provide another value.

Comment: Okay. I am doing something like this right now. So there is definitely nothing that GXT gives out of the box to deal with this right?

Comment: I don't see any such widgets demoed in the GXT examples site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a single control, which can capture multiple values, can you try Multi-Select field like the one explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9328142/gxt-comobobox-with-multi-select-feature/9409765#9409765)?